# dynamic binding and dynamic linking

Tags: terminology, compilation, linkage

1. Quoted from [Dynamic Binding
   C++](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/C%2b%2b-dynamic-binding4.pdf&rct=j&q=%22dynamic%20linking%22%20%22dynamic%20binding%22&ei=_0ePTeO7B4eQ0QGRqvCkCw&usg=AFQjCNET-OSDfoPtTUOOuG3eHVikU4mpDw&sig2=p50J7h8ctP30hbi4FGJCLA&cad=rja),

   > dynamic binding is orthogonal to
   >   dynamic linking...

   I was wondering how to understand
   the meaning of orthogonal"? Is it
   because

   - compilation of source code into  machine code is like going deep, and linkage of various  machine codes is like going horizontal, and so they are orthogonal to each other,
   - (static/dynamic) name binding  is a concept in compilation
   - static/dynamic linking is a concept in linkage?
2. if in dynamic linking, any involved binding, i.e., any involved
   association of objects (data and/or
   code) with identifiers is dynamic
   binding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

"Orthogonal" means that the presence or status (in a more abstract sense) of the one is *not dependent at all* on the corresponding status of the other. In this specific case it means that dynamic linking may occur irrespective of whether dynamic binding occurs, and vice versa.

As a practical example, consider that dynamic binding is the resolution at runtime of what piece of code should be executed as a result of a function call present in the source code. That piece of code may be present in a library which is linked into the executable at link time (static linking), or it may be present in a library dynamically loaded at runtime (dynamic linking). The *binding* part does not care about how the *linking* was done; therefore, it is *orthogonal* to the latter.

You also ask:

> if in dynamic linking, any involved
>   binding, i.e., any involved
>   association of objects (data and/or
>   code) with identifiers is dynamic
>   binding?

This question is meaningless, as there is no *binding* involved in the *linking* process. Binding may occur statically (resolved by the compiler and baked into the object code) or dynamically (resolved at runtime), but the decision of how to bind and the logic that resolves the binding does not interact at all with the linking.

Comment: Thanks! I was also wondering if in dynamic linking, any involved name binding, i.e. any involved association of objects (data and/or code) with identifiers, is dynamic binding?

Comment: @Tim: Binding in compilation == **static** binding (compiler decides on the spot). In dynamic binding, of course the compiler has to decide on the spot to call *something*, but that something is in fact code that will decide at runtime what code to execute for a given expression. That code is what we refer to as the result of the binding, so **dynamic** binding happens at runtime. Therefore, name binding (in general) does not happen only in compilation.